# How to know if my google amp email whitelist registration has been received and actively being reviewed?

Tags: amp-email

Can someone please advise on how I can get an update on where my whitelisting registration/application process is or how much longer I should expect to wait to hear the status of the whitelisting process?

Earlier this week on 6/27, I completed the [amp email whitelisting registration process](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/register) by submitting production-ready emails from our production servers to the required list of emails and also, submitting the registration form.

I haven't heard anything regarding the whitelisting status since then. I also elected to get a copy of my google form submissions to make sure I submitted the form, but I never received those either. The registration page claims to respond "within 5 working days". But, it's around that time frame, and I haven't heard anything. Does anyone have more insight on the expected timeframe or where I can get more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected timeframe is exactly what the registration page says: "within 5 working days". If you don't hear within 5 working days, feel free to escalate to ampforemail+registration@google.com.

Note that delays are expected around US holidays - next week is 4th of July in the US, so you likely won't hear anything until Wednesday next week, if you don't get a response today.

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. I will keep that in mind going forward.